# Decoding MQTT Payloads

Tags: python, mqtt

I have a MQTT message with a payload of:

```
b'\x08\xbd\x81\xc8\xf6\x890\x12D\n0SWD/CATTLE CREEK INJECTION PAD 1/CASING PRESSURE\x18\xd4\xf9\xc7\xf6\x890 \t8\x00J\x00e\xf4\xf6\x1cE\x12E\n1SWD/CATTLE CREEK INJECTION PAD 1/ANNULUS PRESSURE\x18\xd5\xfc\xc7\xf6\x890 \t8\x00J\x00e2\xbd&C\x12D\n0SWD/CATTLE CREEK INJECTION PAD 1/TUBING PRESSURE\x18\xff\xff\xc7\xf6\x890 \t8\x00J\x00e\xa9=nD\x18A'
```

I'm trying to figure out how to parse this data. It looks like the protocol starts the message with

```
\x08\xbd\x81\xc8\xf6\x890\x12D\n0
```

Followed by the data key and corrosponding byte value:

```
SWD/CATTLE CREEK INJECTION PAD 1/CASING PRESSURE\x18\xd4\xf9\xc7\xf6\x890 \t8\x00J\x00e\xf4\xf6\x1cE\x12E\n1

SWD/CATTLE CREEK INJECTION PAD 1/ANNULUS PRESSURE\x18\xd5\xfc\xc7\xf6\x890 \t8\x00J\x00e2\xbd&C\x12D\n0

WD/CATTLE CREEK INJECTION PAD 1/TUBING PRESSURE\x18\xff\xff\xc7\xf6\x890 \t8\x00J\x00e\xa9=nD\x18A
```

Is there a library to quickly parse this into the corresponding floats or integer values? Or any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have access to anything that documents the encoding used to produce these messages?

Comment: Personnaly I use the package [paho_mqtt](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/), quite easy to use

Comment: @Brinfer This question is about decoding a custom MQTT payload after the message has already been delivered to the client, not about just receiving the message.